# ZF2 Route based on method while extending AbstractRestfulController

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-framework-routing

In Zend Framework 2 I am trying to route a few dynamic urls to specified actions in a controller that extends `AbstractRestfulController`, based on the request type. Problem is, the `AbstractRestfulController` keeps overriding these routes to the default actions `get()`, `getList()`, etc.

My routes are:

```
GET /my-endpoint/{other_id} - allAction()
POST /my-endpoint/{other_id} - createAction()
GET /my-endpoint/{other_id}/{id} - getAction()
PUT /my-endpoint/{other_id}/{id} - updateAction()
DELETE /my-endpoint/{other_id}/{id} - deleteAction()
```

My router config is:

```
'my-endpoint' => [
    'type' => 'segment',
    'options' => [
        'route' => 'my-endpoint/:other_id',
        'constraints' => [
            'other_id' => '[0-9]+',
        ],
        'defaults' => [
            'controller' => 'my-endpoint',
        ],
    ],
    'may_terminate' => true,
    'child_routes' => [
        'get' => [
            'type' => 'method',
            'options' => [
                'verb' => 'get',
                'defaults' => [
                    'action' => 'all',
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'post' => [
            'type' => 'method',
            'options' => [
                'verb' => 'post',
                'defaults' => [
                    'action' => 'create',
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'single' => [
            'type' => 'segment',
            'options' => [
                'route' => '[/:id]',
                'constraints' => [
                    'id' => '[0-9]+',
                ],
            ],
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => [
                'get' => [
                    'type' => 'method',
                    'options' => [
                        'verb' => 'get',
                        'defaults' => [
                            'action' => 'get',
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                'update' => [
                    'type' => 'method',
                    'options' => [
                        'verb' => 'put',
                        'defaults' => [
                            'action' => 'update',
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                'delete' => [
                    'type' => 'method',
                    'options' => [
                        'verb' => 'delete',
                        'defaults' => [
                            'action' => 'delete',
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

And my controller has the following actions:

```
public function allAction() {
    die('allAction');
}

public function createAction() {
    die('createAction');
}

public function getAction() {
    die('getAction');
}

public function updateAction() {
    die('updateAction');
}

public function deleteAction() {
    die('deleteAction');
}
```

How can I route specifically this way, so that no other request types are allowed to this controller / overriding the default `AbstractRestfulController` routes?

Also, I would like to continue extending this controller because I am actually extending a more generic controller which extends this Zend one.

Comment: Why not use the [ZF2 `AbstractActionController`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-mvc/blob/master/src/Controller/AbstractActionController.php) for this?

Comment: @Wilt if you read my last sentence, I have a larger base controller that does the extending from Zends controller. I can do funkier routing inside the controllers but it would be cleaner and nicer to do it properly

Comment: Sorry, no I missed that important part. I will try to come up with a usable answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set: `'may_terminate' => false`

Right now your route will match `'my-endpoint'` or `'single'` and since there is [no action set](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-mvc/blob/master/src/Controller/AbstractRestfulController.php#L327) for these matches. Instead it will [get the http method from the request](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-mvc/blob/master/src/Controller/AbstractRestfulController.php#L339) and map to the corresponding controller methods [inside the `AbstractRestfulController` `onDispatch` method](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-mvc/blob/master/src/Controller/AbstractRestfulController.php#L340).

Comment: This did the trick! Thanks, I didn't know what the `may_terminate` really did